# Migration to Oracle Autonomous Database

Tags: oracle, migration

What prerequisites, if any (such as version number, database objects in use), does an existing Oracle database have to fulfil in order to be able to migrate it straight away to *Oracle Autonomous Database*? I've read [the FAQ](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/bi-datawarehousing/adw-technical-faq-public-5069016.pdf) but it doesn't address this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears Oracle version 18c is compatible with Autonomous database, but not prior versions.